# Spring / freemarker include template inconsistent between IDE and command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, freemarker

I have recently updated my project from `Spring boot 1.1.1 to 1.2.6 and Spring version 4.0.5 to 4.1.7.`

After the upgrade, the application runs fine from the IDE i-e `intellij`, but if I run it from command line it gives and error

```
 Free-marker template error (DEBUG mode; use RE THROW in production!): Template inclusion failed (for parameter value "fragments/booking-overview-booking detail.ftl"): Template not found for name "fragments/booking-overview-booking detail.ftl". The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: MultiTemplateLoader(loader1 = org.springframework.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader@141bafe1, loader2 = ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer, basePackagePath="" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg */)). ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: #include "fragments/booking-overview-... [in template "booking-overview.ftl" at line 15, column 1] ---- Java stack trace (for programmers): ---- freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:160) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324) at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302) at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:325) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:367) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:284) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:234) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:55) at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:196) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:293) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:242) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:220) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259) at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169) at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:69) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "fragments/booking-overview-booking detail.ftl". The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: MultiTemplateLoader(loader1 = org.springframework.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader@141bafe1, loader2 = ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer, basePackagePath="" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg */)). at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:1833) at freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForInclusion(Environment.java:2044) at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:158) ... 93 more
```

It can find the main template, but cannot locate the one included in another template. It is working fine on previous versions of `Spring` and `Spring-boot`.

If I change 
`<property name="templateLoaderPaths" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/views/"/>` to `<property name="templateLoaderPaths" value="classpath:/WEB-INF/ftl/views/"/>`

**It works fine in the command line but the IDE causes 404 error**. I couldn't find anything in the Spring release notes that can explain anything. Not sure what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if it can find a file as a resource:

```
URL u = FreeMarkerConfigurer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fragments/booking-overview-booking detail.ftl");
if (u != null) {
         ...
}
```

I've also noticed the blank in the file name, which can cause issues sometime.
Ensure you are useing the correct file separator for your operating system.

```
System.getProperty("file.separator")
```

Comment: I changed the file name to remove the space and it has started working without the classpath. Just wondering why it was working with the previous version of spring and spring boot.